# folding not found error when za is pressed in vim

Tags: vim

I opened a large javascript file in gvim and am trying to use folding, but I cannot get it to work

Im trying

```
zo - opens folds
zc - closes fold
zm - increases auto fold depth
zr - reduces auto fold depth
```

but it says folding does not exist?

Do I have to turn the folding mechanism on?

Why wont this work? Is it a new install of gvim?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The folding behavior depends on the values of a bunch of options. The most important is `foldmethod` which dictates how folds are calculated. You can see its value with `:set foldmethod?` which should tell you which of these methods, `manual`, `indent`, `expr`, `marker`, `syntax`, `diff`, is currently in use. Refer to `:help 'foldmethod'` and the linked help sections for details.

`manual` is the default method where folds have to be created manually with `zf` before being opened or closed.

With `indent`, folds are automatically calculated for you based on indenting, with `syntax` they are calculated based on the filetype-specific syntax rules.